# How to know if a beginning 'v' is pronounced /f/ or /v/?

Tags: pronunciation, consonant-sounds

A 'v' in the beginning of a word can be pronounced in one of two ways:

- /f/: *Vater*, *verrückt*, *vier*, *Vogel*.
- /v/: *Vanille*, *Verb*, *Villa*, *Vokal*, *vulgär*.

My question: Is there a way to know how a word should be pronounced without looking it up?

Bonus question: Wiktionary has a lot of *ver*-words transcribed with /v/, e.g. *verleben*, *vergammelt*, *vernetzen*. Are they pronounced like that in some dialect?

Comment: I couldn't come up with a /f/-word that begins in "vu" or "vi" (but not in "vie"), but would love to have such an example if there is one.

Comment: vulgär, Vulkan, both /v/ (foreign origin). Words beginning with "vi" only are all of foreign origin and pronounced /v/. Words beginning with "vie" are most likely of Germanic origin, vier, Vieh, viel.

Comment: Many Bavarians pronounce all of the *v*s as /f/. Some (like me) do it for comedic effect. ‘Oh, das sind schöne Blumen, ich hol mal eine *Fase’ works like a charm in giving people confused looks.

Answer (score 11):

In most cases (and true for your examples):

- Germanic words are pronounced /f/.
- Loan-words (especially Latin) are pronounced /v/.

In particular, true German words starting with "ver-" are pronounced /f/, but not "Verdikt", say.

Comment: True German words starting with "ver-" are pronounced /f/, not /v/.

Comment: I think this is another example of a difference most people wouldn't notice. At least for myself I can say I've never noticed that "Vater" and "Vanille" start with a different sound. It's much the same as the different "S"s, I think.

Answer (score 4):

The letter V is pronounced /f/ except for words of foreign origin.

> Vanille, Verb, Villa, Vulgär, Vulkan, Vase

Answer (score 1):

I never heard a German dialect that uses /v/ for words like ver(-)gammelt. I have lived in the west and north of Germany and in Berlin.